# Why is height returning 0

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a rotating slideshow on the homepage, and want to set the height of the content based on the height of the image minus the height of the title minus the height of the arrows. For some reason neither the height of the title or image are being returned as anything but 0.

see here: http://www.keganquimby.com/lumina/

the excerpt (content under the title next to the image) cuts into the arrows when the image isn't tall enough, so I'd like to set it with CSS based on the image height.

my js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.slides .slide').each(function(){

    var slideHeight = $(this).height();
    var headerHeight = $('.slide-content header').height();
    var arrowHeight = $('.flex-direction-nav').height();

    var contentHeight = slideHeight - headerHeight - arrowHeight;

    });
});
```

NEW JS (edited to set the height, and pull the other height calls outside the each loop):

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){

var slideHeight = $(this).height();
var headerHeight = $('.slide-content header').height();
var arrowHeight = $('.flex-direction-nav').height();

$('.slides .slide').each(function(){

    var contentHeight = slideHeight - headerHeight - arrowHeight;
    $('footer.post-more').css('height', contentHeight + 'px');

    });
});
```

Comment: Avoid DOM queries within loops. Cache `$('.slide-content header').height()` (and that other height) before the `.each()`.

Comment: Generally, you cannot reliably read the height of an image on DOM-ready, as the image has not fully loaded at that point (unless it's cached). I guess, you'll have to do a `$( document ).on( 'load', ...`.

Comment: pulling the DOM queries outside the loop causes only one number to be returned.

Comment: You're doing `.height()` on both queries, so you'll get two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for the images to load before measuring their height. Note that the DOM readiness doesn't mean that the images have been loaded. Try this instead:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){
    var headerHeight = $('.slide-content header').height(),
        arrowHeight = $('.flex-direction-nav').height();

    var imgHeights = $('.slides .slide').map(function() {
        return $(this).height() - headerHeight - arrowHeight;
    });
});
```

From [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

Comment: @pst not really.. `.ready` waits for the DOM, `load` - for all the assets, like images, videos, frames etc.

Comment: I tried window load as well, but it still doesn't work. Take a look. Per comment above, I pulled the height calls outside the loop.

Comment: oh sorry it doesn't set the height yet. it's just finding the height, and then it'll set the height.

okay now it does :)

Comment: you don't move `var slideHeight = $(this).height();` outside of the loop - it has to be calculated for *each* image

Comment: oh woopsie. still not returning anything :(

Comment: that still returns 0 when implemented... perhaps there's another JS conflict somewhere?